# Who is "the superficial man"?

Tags: meaning, articles

> She possesses many other qualities prized by **the superficial man**.

My understanding is—whoever says it, doesn't refer to himself by *the superficial man*. The superficial man is some hypothetical person that represents all superficial men in the society. In the same fashion you say "The activities associated with **the common man**."

There are three ways to say this:

> She possesses many other qualities prized by **the** superficial **man**.
>
> She possesses many other qualities prized by **a** superficial **man**.
>
> She possesses many other qualities prized by superficial **men**.

Are any of these sentences incorrect? Why is the first one preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. It is a reflection of HER qualities. They are prized by men who are superficial.

*The superficial man* is a collective title like *Homo Erectus*, hence *a superficial man* or *superficial men* are not giving the same effect.

*He is **a drinking man*** has the same idiomatic feeling to it

Comment: It's a [definite generic noun phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Comment: Does look like it on the surface, but what would "a drinking man" then be? "The drinking man" sounds strange

Comment: A man who drinks. The drinking man will appreciate this scotch; so will drinking men in general. And it's even true that a drinking man would appreciate this scotch, because it's a criterial scotch; if he doesn't, he isn't what I call a drinking man. The generalizations, you see, are always vague and impressional, which is usually what's desired.

Comment: I mean the term "a drinking man" like "a loose woman"

Comment: Might be. Depends on the speaker's feelings. Or it might be a term of respect. Or nostalgia. Or anything. Like I said, it's vague.